# Converting a Batch script to Shell

Tags: shell, batch-file

I'm trying to convert a Batch script to a shell. The script collect the name of the file that start with a certain String, and simply log it.

**here is my batch Script :**

```
PATH = E:/DATA
str_Begin_With = Employee
set FILE_NAME= for %%x in (%PATH%/%str_Begin_With%*.txt) do set FILE_NAME=%%~x
ECHO %FILE_NAME%
```

**This is my Shell attempt:**

```
export FILE_NAME=
for x in [$PATH/$str_Begin_With*.txt]; 
do FILE_NAME= x
```

Can someone explain to me how does it work on shell, i'm not familiar with it

Comment: Since the batch isn't valid it is difficult to guess what you have in mind.

Comment: It looks like bash that somebody tried to convert to batch

Comment: the batch is valid, i've tried it, i just don't know how to convert it to shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using ***Basename***.

In your Case:

```
for file in "$PATH"/$str_Begin_With*.txt
do
NAME=$(basename "$file")
echo "$NAME"
done
```

Comment: that's what i was looking for ! Thank's